# I can't set a different baseURL in my nuxt app using Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to set the baseURL for my nuxt app so it makes requests from the swapi api, but it always goes to localhost:3000, although I'm following the documentation it seems that I am unable to solve this issue.

My nuxt.config.js is this:

```
modules: [
'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
'@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

axios: {
    // proxyHeaders: false
    baseURL:"https://swapi.dev/api/"
},
```

And in my file /.nuxt/axios.js the code for the baseURL looks at follow:

```
 const baseURL = process.browser
  ? 'https://swapi.dev/api/'
  : (process.env._AXIOS_BASE_URL_ || 'https://swapi.dev/api/')
```

For vue apps, I usually have a plugins/axios.js file where I would put:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL =
process.env.baseURL || process.env.apiUrl || "https://swapi.dev/api/";
```

But I think I don't need this with Nuxt.

Answer (score 1):

If you would be using the base URL in the whole of your application, you must be setting the base URL in Nuxt config, or create const file, and import it anywhere!

In const file:

```
export const BASE_URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "https://localhost:3000" : "https://swapi.dev/api/";
```

OR
In the Nuxt config:

```
const BASE_URL = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "https://localhost:3000" : "https://swapi.dev/api/";
```